# SQL Query to calculate total time worked and total distance travelled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to write an SQL Query which calculates the `Total Time worked` and `Total Distance Traveled` by a Driver for each date.

The StartOfDay is the `MIN(LogDateTime) WHERE EventCode = 1`
The EndOfDay is the `MAX(LogDateTime) WHERE EventCode = 2`

```
Note: EventCode = 1 (Journey Start) AND EventCode = 2 (Journey End)
```

The Total Distance is `SUM` of All records Between `EventCode = 1 AND EventCode = 2` (there can be more than one pair of EventCode = 1 AND EventCode = 2 Per Day)

**Sample Data and Query: [Here](http://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/517070/calculate-the-total-time-worked-and-total-distance-travelled)**

This is the Query:

```
    SELECT
             DriverId 
            ,AssetId
            ,StartOfDay
            ,EndOfDay

            ,WorkedTimeHHMMSS = DATEDIFF(SECOND, StartOfDay, EndOfDay)

-- Adding the Distances for Each Date
            ,TotalDistance = SUM(DistanceCovered) --OVER(PARTITION BY StartOfDay)
        FROM (

            SELECT 
                 AssetId = ignOn.AssetId
                ,DriverId = ignOn.DriverId
                ,EventCode = p.EventCode
                ,LogDate = FORMAT(p.LogDateTime, 'dd-MMM-yyyy')
                ,LogDateTime = p.LogDateTime

-- MIN EventCode = 1
                ,StartOfDay = MIN(ignOn.LogDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY ignOn.DriverId, ignOn.AssetId, CAST(ignOn.LogDateTime AS DATE))

-- MAX EventCode = 2
                ,EndOfDay = MAX(ignOff.LogDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY ignOff.DriverId, ignOff.AssetId, CAST(ignOff.LogDateTime AS DATE))

-- Calculate the Distance of Current Point to the Next Point
                ,DistanceCovered = p.GeoLocation.STDistance(
                                        LEAD(p.GeoLocation) OVER(PARTITION BY ignOn.AssetId, ignOn.LogDateTime ORDER BY p.LogDateTime))

            FROM #VehicleLogs ignOn
            CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT top(1) LogId, EventCode, LogDateTime, GeoLocation , DriverId, AssetId
                FROM #VehicleLogs  WHERE 
                AssetId = ignOn.AssetId AND LogDateTime > ignOn.LogDateTime AND EventCode = 2
                ORDER by LogDateTime
            ) ignOff
            INNER JOIN #VehicleLogs p ON p.AssetId = ignOn.AssetId AND p.LogDateTime >= ignOn.LogDateTime AND p.LogDateTime <= ignOff.LogDateTime
            WHERE 
                --ignOn.LogDateTime BETWEEN @utcStartDate AND @utcEndDate
                AND ignOn.DriverId = 7
                AND ignOn.EventCode = 1
            ) K
        GROUP BY StartOfDay, EndOfDay, DriverId, AssetId
```

This is the result I am getting:

[image]

As you can see that there is more than one record for `StartOfDay = 2016-06-30 21:35:11.000` - but the EndOfDay is different for both records

This is happening because there is an overnight journey - The Journey Starts on `30-06-2016` but ends on `01-07-2016`

[image]

Above result can be generated using this Query:

```
            SELECT 
            LogId = p.LogId
            ,AssetId = ignOn.AssetId
            ,DriverId = ignOn.DriverId
            ,EventCode = p.EventCode
            ,LogDate = FORMAT(p.LogDateTime, 'dd-MMM-yyyy')
            ,LogDateTime = p.LogDateTime
            ,StartOfDay = MIN(ignOn.LogDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY ignOn.DriverId, ignOn.AssetId, CAST(ignOn.LogDateTime AS DATE))
            ,EndOfDay = MAX(ignOff.LogDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY ignOff.DriverId, ignOff.AssetId, CAST(ignOff.LogDateTime AS DATE))
            ,DistanceCovered = p.GeoLocation.STDistance(
                                    LEAD(p.GeoLocation) OVER(PARTITION BY ignOn.AssetId, ignOn.LogDateTime ORDER BY p.LogDateTime))

        FROM #VehicleLogs ignOn
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT top(1) LogId, EventCode, LogDateTime, GeoLocation , DriverId, AssetId
            FROM #VehicleLogs  WHERE 
            AssetId = ignOn.AssetId AND LogDateTime > ignOn.LogDateTime AND EventCode = 2
            ORDER by LogDateTime
        ) ignOff
        INNER JOIN #VehicleLogs p ON p.AssetId = ignOn.AssetId AND p.LogDateTime >= ignOn.LogDateTime AND p.LogDateTime <= ignOff.LogDateTime
        WHERE 
           -- ignOn.LogDateTime BETWEEN @utcStartDate AND @utcEndDate
            AND ignOn.DriverId = 7
            AND ignOn.EventCode = 1
```

**The Question is:**

How can I handle overnight Journeys?

The business rule for overnight Journeys is that they should be split between the 2 days OR calculated for the day they finish.

**Other Rules**

1. A driver can drive more than one vehicle per day
2. The data should be sorted by `LogDateTime ASC` Not `LogId`

**Sample Data and Query: [Here](http://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/517070/calculate-the-total-time-worked-and-total-distance-travelled)**

Comment: Can we assome ordering of logid is sequential with respect to time?

Comment: @Vérace not really in some cases LogId is not sequential w.r.t time

Comment: Ok, what is the business logic for overnight journeys. They are calculated on the day that they start or they are split between 2 days or they are calculated for the day they finish? Also as @Vérace remarked and you answer - what is the order of all set - you have to order it somehow to calculate this?

Comment: @Vérace, I think you mean *assume* not *assome*?

Comment: Yeah, typo - oops! :-)

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov the Order of the data should be by LogDateTime Ascending Order - and the Business Logic for over night Journey is that they should be split between the 2 days - if that is not possible they should be calculated on the day they finish

Comment: I suppose 1 driver drives only 1 asset?

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov No a driver can drive more than one asset during a day.

Comment: It is good for you to edit the question and remark those things. In that case I don't know. I think of ordering data in proper way and make the set join itself with so we have match begin of event end of event. In that case we can calculate each drive length in time and sum all those. I count on ordering by `DriverId` and `LogDateTime`, but when you told me that `AssetId` can be driven by different drivers during the day my scheme is not working. As advice from me I think it will be better to log start of the event inside the end event. In that case you can easily calculate it.

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov How can I do it by logging the start event inside the end event?

Comment: I can not say for sure (I don't know your software design), but as an example when you log End event you can find last Start event for this driver and this asset (he must start with particular vehicle) and add it to End Event. Then the calculation will be very easy.